# What is "fat bundle"?

Tags: osgi, bundle

I hear the slang term "fat bundle" in OSGi context so I am wondering what is the difference  between it and the ordinary OSGi bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fat bundle is a bundle that contains all its dependencies. Since a bundle has an internal classpath you can take an application and run it inside a bundle. Once you have this "fat" bundle you can carve out pieces and make the more modular.